# Zoomable Image ignores Box() dimension after upgrading Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

After upgrading from compose 1.0.1 to 1.3.0-beta01 my Zoomable Image is ignoring the parent Box dimensions (250x250)
I can even zoom it so large that It reaches over the TopAppBar…

[image]

I didn't changed anything on the code, just simply upgraded to the latest compose version.

Here my ZoomRotationImage Composable:

```
@Composable
private fun ZoomRotationImage(customImageUri: Uri) {

    var zoom by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) } 
    var angle by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    val imageModifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTransformGestures(
                onGesture = { gestureCentroid, gesturePan, gestureZoom, gestureRotate ->
                    val oldScale = zoom
                    val newScale = zoom * gestureZoom
 
                    offset = (offset + gestureCentroid / oldScale).rotateBy(gestureRotate) -
                            (gestureCentroid / newScale + gesturePan / oldScale)
                    zoom = newScale.coerceIn(0.5f..5f)
                    angle += gestureRotate
 

                }
            )
        }
        .graphicsLayer {
            translationX = -offset.x * zoom
            translationY = -offset.y * zoom
            scaleX = zoom
            scaleY = zoom
            rotationZ = angle
            TransformOrigin(0f, 0f).also { transformOrigin = it }
        }

    //GlideImage(customImageUri, modifier = imageModifier, contentScale = ContentScale.Fit)
    AsyncImage(model = customImageUri, contentDescription ="", modifier = imageModifier, contentScale = ContentScale.Fit)


}
```

And here the Box:

```
Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(250.dp)
                .width(250.dp)
        ) {


                ZoomRotationImage(screenState.customImageURI)
    
}
```

Comment: May i ask where you get this rotation code and that color picker?

Comment: @Thracian I think from this repository: https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials

Comment: You should use color picker here. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Color-Picker-Bundle The one in tutorial is obsolete. I wasn't able to figure out how to draw diamond shape correctly when i put it there.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71423294/how-to-create-hsl-saturation-and-lightness-change-gradient-or-brush-editor-with

Comment: @Thracian Thank you, for my use case the simple one is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't call `Modifier.clipToBounds()`, Modifier.clip() before Modifier.graphicsLayer{} or call clip = true inside `Modifier.graphicsLayer{}` your Composable's transformation won't be limited to its bounds. Same goes for drawing to Canvas or using `Modifier.drawX` modifiers either.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Modifier.clipToBounds()` to limit your transformation to limit to bounds of composable to which it is assigned.

Comment: You don' limit to parent's bounds. You limit to composable bounds that Modifier.clipToBounds is assigned to